# 'libxml/xmlversion.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmpp, chat

These kind of error are showing in the 16 files.

When i am going to change then its showing the pop-up

[image]

or click on unlock

[image]

My question is this -

How to unlock this file to editing ?

Comment: are you trying to unlock custom library files?

Comment: if you are trying to edit Library file or complied static libraries ".h" file then you are on wrong way...

else as per message you can update permission using terminal ..

Comment: Can you explain How? @kalpeshjetani

Comment: here i found same question : http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/68646/how-do-i-unlock-a-plist-file-so-that-i-can-change-it

Comment: if you do edit in system or compiled library.. mean you are editing supportive ".h" function visibility files, and you are not editing actual source or function, thus this kind of error could occur..

Comment: @kalpeshjetani .. How to add actual source ... can you explain in details?

Comment: you need to rebuild the library, if you want to add some feature to system library you can use category (Objective-C) Or extension (Swift).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the code from git through `Download Zip`. Try `git clone` to download the code.

Answer (score 0):

Like the message box says, find the files in Finder and right click them. Modify their permissions to be writable.

Comment: I have already tried, but there is no option for changing the permissions .

Comment: Can you please tell me the name on the right click ? which option i am going to click .

Comment: "Get Info" -> Permissions -> Owner. Check that "write" box is enabled.

Comment: I have tried but it is still showing same popup . and also tried with restart Xcode also.